# Creating custom metric with GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am new to [GTM](http://www.google.dk/tagmanager/) V2.

I would like to track PDF downloads using custom metric. I can built custom dimension for the same, but am not able to create custom metric.

I want report similar to below:

```
PDFname        no. of download
xyx                   1
abc                   5
```

- xyz pdf downloaded 1 time abc 5
- PDF name and no. of download are column heading , rest are it values

I want to create metric using GTM v2.  I don't want to write JavaScript for the same. I have done above report using event tracking, but want to do the same with custom metric

Please explain in detail on how to create custom metric, using GTM.

Please help me on the same as soon as possible.

Comment: Welcome to stack:  can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have created a event tag with trigger with condition which fire on the pages which have PDF's and click text for the PDF. I have also made  tag to act as dimension were i can fetch PDF name

Comment: I have created a event tag with trigger with condition which fire on the pages which have PDF's and click text for the PDF. I have also made  tag to act as dimension were i can fetch PDF name. THe problem is that i am not able to write custom metric for the same. Actually i have never  created custom metric using GTMV2 so i am not aware how to use it . please help assumeme as biggner for GTMV2

Comment: In the Google Analytics tag template there is actually a field to enter custom metrics - i.e. you create a custom metric in your Analytics admin area, enter the numeric index in the Custom Metrics->Index field and in the metric value field you enter the number by which you want the metric to be incremented (usually 1). Is that what you are after - then I can turn this into an answer. Else clarify.

Comment: Thanks Eike for the respon  and Time: I am aware of this methodolgy my concers is how in custom metric i can associate numbers to particular PDF  dowload, like xyz  PDF was download 5 times . Also how can  write a tag , Trigger and link it to particular custom dimension as i have many dimensions . I am fresher and new to GTM V2 . I will be thankful if you can share an example were u created a dimension and its associated metric for tracking  Thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand; if you pass 1 as metric value the custom metric will be incremented by 1 every time your tag is triggered (i.e. if you use event tracking to track downloads and pass in a metric value of 1 every time your tracker count 1 forward every time someone downloads a pdf).

Comment: thanks Eike and apology for the confusion please also answer my below query. how can link a custom metric to a particular dimension so that i associates value for the custom metric to that  particular dimension (e.g  i have 4 custom dimension say "A", "B","C","D" and i have created a custom metric "Z ")  i want associated Z custom metric with custom Dimension "A' only . How can I do that ? so that value from Z is only pass to A not to other Dimension. Is there any way to write Tag,Trigger and link dimension and metric

Comment: hi Eike can u pls help ?

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of Google Tag Manager, 'Macros' have been renamed to 'Variables' so I will be referring to them as such.

I implemented a tag which tracks when a PDF is downloaded on my website. I did this by creating a custom Variable. Follow the steps to create the variables required to track PDF downloads.

1) Create a new variable called 'element', make this variable an 'auto-event' variable. Select 'Element' from the Variable Type drop-down menu. Click 'Save Variable'

2) Create a new variable called 'Click Link File Name'. Make this variable a Custom Javascript Variable. Insert the following code into the configure variable field.

```
function() {
    var filepath = {{element}}.pathname.split("/");
    var filename = filepath.pop();
    return filename.indexOf(".")>-1?filename:'n/a';
}
```

Click 'Save Variable'

3) Create the Trigger - Name the Trigger "PDF Download"

- Event : Click
- Configure: Just Links
- Enable When: [Page URL] [matches RegEx] .*
- FireOn: [Click URL Path] [matches RegEx] .(pdf)$

4) Create the Tag

- Product : Google Analytics
- Tag Type : Universal Analytics
- Configure Tag:

  - Tracking Id : "Your Tracking Code Here"
  - Track Type  : "Event"
  - Category    : "Click"
  - Action      : "Download"
  - Label       : "{{Click Link File Name}}"
- Fire On: "PDF Download"

What this set of instructions will do for you is set up variables able to record the name of your PDF file as well as the ability to track it as an event. The trigger that we set up in step 3 tells GTM to ACTIVATE the tag on every page (.*) and FIRE the tag when the user CLICKS a link ending with the string ".pdf". The tag we set up tells GTM to send an event to your GA Account with the category, action and label listed above. The label of the event will contain the name of the PDF file that was downloaded.

If you want any more customization than this let me know and I will provide you with a solution to track things like
 - Which page the PDF was downloaded from

Comment: "In the new version of Google Tag Manager, 'Metrics' have been renamed to 'Variables'" - uhm, no. "Macros" have been renamed "Variables". GTM does not have metrics (it's not a tracking tool).

Comment: Thanks Eike, misuse of language.