# Google tag manager - how does it work? (Architecture)

Tags: google-tag-manager

I don't know if this is the right place to ask but it is programming (in a way). How does the Google tag manager work?

The way I see it:

1. page loads
2. GTM code loads and does it's thing
   _makes checks
   _creates dataLayer object
   _invokes gtm.js library (loads it whole in the browser)
   _pushes basic objects into dataLayer
   _"imports" tags, triggers and variables
   _attaches them to document nodes
3. any tags configured to fire on 'pageLoad' fire (push data into dataLayer)
4. DOM ready (any tags configured for 'DOM ready' fire)
5. window loads (any tags configured for 'windowLoaded' fire )
6. 'triggers' ('rules') wait attached to proper DOM nodes

User interacts with the document (page):

1. events occur
2. rules ('triggers') are evaluated
3. rules trigger tags
4. tags push events' info into dataLayer

How does this data from the dataLayer then get sent to Google Analytics, AdWords or other configured services? Which piece of code does this?

Is is possible that the tag that was responsible for pushing the event into the dataLayer also sends it to GA service? OR is there some other generic GA tag that picks up everything that was written into the DL and then sends it to the GA?

How do variables fit into this story? The way I see it it can be both written to a variable (a tag can store something into a pre-set up variable) or something can be pre-defined in a variable and used by the tag.

Thanks for any clariffication on this.

Comment: I will vote to close this as off-topic ("too broad" and/or "question about general software" etc), but as a tip, download the gtm.js file with your container id (gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXX) and you will find, albeit in compressed/obfuscated form, all configured tags. triggers and variables at the end of the file.

Comment: No problem, I appologise if I made an error in posting. But I really dont know where to post these things. It's not code (just code) but it's definitely not for SuperUser. Or...? :)

Comment: You can post to Webmasters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have everything basically correct except "4: tags push event info into dataLayer".

Tags are what send the data to the data/analytic platform of your choice.

Most often you will be using a "Universal Analytics" Tag that requires a UA code. The tag will automatically send whatever kind of data you want to your GA account. You can send the following

- Pageview
- Event
- Transaction
- Social
- Timing
- Decorate Link
- Decorate Form

Each one of these items require configuration as to allow you to send different types of information. For example, when sending an event, you need to include event category, event action and event label.

The way variables work is as you mentioned:

> "something can be pre-defined in a variable and used by the tag"

So for example, there is no GTM-pre-defined variable to grab the filename off of a download button. So I can create a variable on my own and then reference that variable when using Triggers or Tags. The actual variables are pushed to the data layer can be found there when in preview mode.

To wrap it up.
If you want to track pdf downloads as an event see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30978193/creating-custom-metric-with-gtm/31565570#31565570) post. Look for my answer on the page and it should provide you with a more comprehensive and applicable answer to your question.

Hope this provides you with some clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Tags are what send the data to analytics platform (GA or other). And the tag javascript snippet that talks to analytics platform resides within gtm.js

When we configure container through GTM UI, adequate tag (javascript code) gets added to gtm.js for your container. Every site owner who uses GTM gets a different gtm.js based on their configuration (that is the purpose of id parameter to gtm.js). Infact, https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js will lead to 404.

You can try https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=YOUR_CONTAINER_ID as you add different tags and you can see different gtm.js files.

That's how tag management products achieve inserting code snippet within sites without needing any alterations to the actual site pages (beyond inserting the initial container tag related code, ofcourse).